# Error: Unable to resolve module `./build/index` from `index.js`: The development server return error code 500

Tags: react-native, android-emulator

I have to build an existing project code. I am facing some issues. Build is successful, but on emulator I get this:

> The development server return error code 500

...and on the metro I get this error message:

> error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `./build/index` from `index.js`

Anyone has any idea what is causing the error and how to solve it?

[Image from emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvoHn.png)

[and this image is from metro cli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih2YO.png)

These are my dependency versions:

```
 -  "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "^2.9.0",
 -  "apollo-boost": "^0.4.7",
 -  "graphql": "^14.6.0",
 -  "react": "16.9.0",
 -  "react-apollo": "^3.1.3",
 -  "react-devtools": "^3.6.3",
 -  "react-native": "0.61.2",
 -  "react-native-notifications": "^3.1.2"
 -  node version v12.18.3
 -  npm version 6.14.6
 -  react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

Comment: Hello @Zia Sultani,
Can you share your `index.js` file because it crashes from an `import` or `require` calling. If you have a `build` folder, simply delete it and reset the bundler and re-run the project.

Comment: Hello @Ronan , Thanks for responding actually previous developer changed some file and folder name that is why it was giving this error but it is resolved now. my background is from phonegap that is why react native error messages is a little new for me. again Thanks again for responding .